# Trying to position a image in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner at CSS and HTML and I am coding a landing page for an upcoming application. I am trying to align the title (image) on the page roughly in the center, but higher up on the y axis.

Please can you tell me why the CSS in this code is not repositioning the image but retaining the image in the top left hand corner?

```
<header><title>title</title></header>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image:url('Background.png');
    }
    title {
        top:30px;
        right:50px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class=body></div>
<div class=title><img src='title.png'></img></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it a position property. Also, your selector isn't correct:

```
.title {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is incorrect youre missing the leading `.` should be:

```
.title {
        top:30px;
        right:50px;
        position: absolute; /* or relative depending... */
    }
```

Additionally you shoudl really enclose your attribute values on the html elements in double quotes `"`.

And the image tag cannot have child elements so its closed with short syntax typically like:

`<img src="myimage.jpg" />`

You should also put your `style` tag in the `head` element (its `head` NOT `header`).

Comment: To support prodigitalson's point regarding quoting attribute values, I refer to the W3: [http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.4); though I'm not aware that any requirement that they be in double-quotes, rather than single.

Comment: @David Thomas: You might find this interesting: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values

Comment: @thirtydot, very much so (thanks for the reference!); it (strongly) suggests (though doesn't **prove**) that prodigitalson was incorrect in his assertion that attribute values must be double-quoted. Though it supports my iirc-notion that single-quotes are allowed.

Comment: i wasnt saying they have to be double quoted... you can use single quotes as well. If there are no spaces then you dont even have to have quotes. I only mentioned it because its a good habit to get in to. If youre using HTML 4.01 you dont have to close tags either but id never suggest that its ok not to.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, you need to set

```
 position:absolute;
```

on the div.title.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Wvkvw/1/

Also

1) You define classes on your divs, but don't refer to them in your styles - you need to use .classname syntax.

2) You should use "" around your class names:

```
<div class="classname">
```

3) Finally - I wouldn't recommend using "body" as a stylename - it just leads to confusion